# JS функция в качестве аргумента

Tags: javascript

Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы в консоль выводилось первое вычисленное значение.
При этом нельзя изменять переменную data, должна остаться как определено ниже.

```js
function getInc(inc) {
  // решение
}

let data = getInc( (i) => { return ++i } )

console.log( data(10) ); //11
console.log( data(20) ); //11
console.log( data(30) ); //11
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нужно просто сохранить первый результат в замыкании:

```js
function getInc(inc) {
  const NO_CALL_FLAG = Symbol();
  let res = NO_CALL_FLAG;
  return function(arg){
    // если ещё не вычисляли, вычисляем и сохраняем в замыкании
    return res === NO_CALL_FLAG ? res = inc(arg) : res; 
  };
}

let data = getInc( (i) => { return ++i })

console.log( data(10) ); //11
console.log( data(20) ); //11
console.log( data(30) ); //11

// ещё пример:
let twice = getInc(i => 2*i);
console.log(twice(5), twice(3)); // 10 10
```

*Если нужна поддержка функций с количеством аргументов отличных от 1, достаточно оба `arg` заменить на `...args`*

Comment: Upvote, но позвольте позанудствовать: а вдруг исполнение первой функции вернуло как раз `undefined`?)

Comment: я как раз думал об этом в тот момент, когда в соседнем решении как раз появилось решение этой проблемы)

Comment: Добавил Symbol =)

Comment: вот теперь точно красота)

Answer (score 3):

Нужно сохранить параметр в замыкании что функция вызывалась. И сохранить результат первого вызова, чтобы потом всегда возвращать его.

```js
function getInc(_function) {
  let isFunctionCall = false;
  let functionResult = null;
  
  return (...args) => {
    if (!isFunctionCall) {
      isFunctionCall = true;
      functionResult = _function(...args);
    }
    return functionResult;
  }
}

let data = getInc((i) => { return ++i })

console.log( data(10) ); //11
console.log( data(20) ); //11
console.log( data(30) ); //11
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function getInc(inc, val) {
   let i = val
   return () => inc(i)
}

let data = getInc((i) => ++i, 10)

console.log(data(10)); //11
console.log(data(20)); //11
console.log(data(30)); //11
```

Правда я немного изменил сигнатуру `getInc` и первое значение надо передавать при получении `data`.

Вариант без изменённой сигнатуры.

```
function getInc(inc) {
   let i = 0
   return val => i ? i : i = inc(val)
}

let data = getInc((i) => ++i)

console.log(data(10)); //11
console.log(data(20)); //11
console.log(data(30)); //11
```

Answer (score -1):

Возможно я не понял вопрос, ответ:

```
function getInc(inc) {
  // решение
  return (j) => 11;
}
```

Comment: Этот ответ хорош для ревностных адептов TDD. Пока не появятся новые тесты - этой реализации достаточно =)